# Como agregar propiedades personalizadas al payload JWT Sprint Java

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, oauth2

Usando Spring OAuth2. Implementé una autorización y un servidor de recursos junto con una cierta configuración de seguridad web. Ahora quiero editar la parte de los claims(propiedades del token) y agregar propiedades personalizadas, por ejemplo, email y rol de un usuario, etc. qué debo hacer para agregar propiedades adicionales al payload? Gracias.

Estoy trabajando con Spring Boot 1.5 y tengo la configuración en un directorio, CONFIG pero no estoy claro de donde debo pasarle el rol al proceso de autenticación, básicamente mediante postman le paso el usuario y el password, no se como pasar el rol para que sea parte del token y poder validar por ejemplo en la llamada al rest controller @preauthorize( hasrole('role_admin') )

acá parte del código
RESTController:

```
@Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/count", method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
                    produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity countUsers(@RequestBody(required=false) UserSearchFilterDTO userFilter) {
        CountDTO counts = new CountDTO();
        counts.setUserCount(userManagementService.countUsers(userFilter));
        return new ResponseEntity(counts, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
AuthorizationServerConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.jwt.client_secret}")
    private String CLIENT_SECRET;
    @Value("${security.jwt.client_id}")
    private String CLIENT_ID;
    @Value("${security.jwt.grant_type_password}")
    private String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD;
    @Value("${security.jwt.grant_type_password}")
    private String AUTHORIZATION_CODE;
    @Value("${security.jwt.refresh_token}")
    private String REFRESH_TOKEN;
    @Value("${security.jwt.implicit}")
    private String IMPLICIT;
    @Value("${security.jwt.scope_read}")
    private String SCOPE_READ;
    @Value("${security.jwt.scope_write}")
    private String SCOPE_WRITE;
    @Value("${security.jwt.trust}")
    private String TRUST;
    @Value("${security.jwt.signin_key}")
    private String SIGNIN_KEY;
    @Value("${security.jwt.access_tokn_validity_seconds}")
    private int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS;
    @Value("${security.jwt.frefresh_tokn_validity_seconds}")
    private int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(SIGNIN_KEY);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .authorities()
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

ResourceServerConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.resource_id}")
    private String RESOURCE_ID;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*
        *  here configure the security zone:
        *           the resource /oauth/token is public and not security
        *           the resource /user is private only for admin role
        *           any resources in the itaca are in secure zone and need use the token
        */
        http
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize**", "/public").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .formLogin() // if exist form  login
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()    // if exist form or process logout
                .permitAll();
    }

}

SecurityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.jwt.signin_key}")
    private String SIGNIN_KEY;

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize**", "/public").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(SIGNIN_KEY);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    //Making this primary to avoid any accidental duplication with another token service instance of the same name
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si pones en contexto tu pregunta, con ejemplo de código en el que quieres hacer lo descrito, seria mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Parte del problema es que no estoy claro en donde debo colocarlo, es auth2 y jwt